# How to make a Django form for a model that has a OneToOne connection with the base User model?

Tags: django, model

The details are in the code, it speaks for itself.
I have this profile model with fields that aren't in User,
and I need to make a form that fills up both the fields from User and Profile:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        to=User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False)
    avatar = models.ImageField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.string()
    
    def absolute_url(self):
        return f"/post/{self.pk}/"
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'profile'
        ordering = ['-user']

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = UsernameField(
        max_length=256,
        label=_('RegisterUsername'),
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs= {
                'class': "form-control"
            }
        ),
    )
    email = forms.CharField(
        max_length=320,
        label=_('RegisterEmail'),
        widget=forms.EmailInput(
            attrs= {
                'class': "form-control"
            }
        ),
    )
    nickname = forms.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        label=_('RegisterUsername'),
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs= {
                'class': "form-control"
            }
        ),
    )
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        label=_('RegisterPassword1'),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs= {
                'class': "form-control"
            }
        ),
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        label=_('RegisterPassword2'),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs= {
                'class': "form-control"
            }
        ),
    )
    avatar = forms.ImageField(
        label=_('UploadAvatar'),
        widget=forms.FileInput(
            attrs= {
                'class': "btn btn-outline"
            }
        ),
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            'username', 
            'email'
            'nickname'
            'password1', 
            'password2', 
            'avatar', 
        ]
```

django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (emailnicknamepassword1) specified for Profile

I expected it to work somehow...

Comment: `auth_user` dont have fileld `nickname`. unless you use custom `User`

Answer (score 0):

in your views.py

```
if request.method == "POST":
        
    raw_nickname = request.POST['nickname']
    raw_email = request.POST['email']
    raw_password = request.POST['password']
    raw_first_name = request.POST['first_name']
    raw_last_name = request.POST['last_name']
    raw_avatar = request.POST['avatar']

    user = User.objects.create(
        username=raw_nickname,
        email=raw_email,
        password=raw_password,
        first_name=raw_first_name,
        last_name=raw_last_name
    )

    Profile.objects.create(
        user=user,
        rating=raw_rating,
        avatar=raw_avatar,
    )
```